# Reinstall Grub in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, grub2, reinstall

I upgraded from 14.04 which had Gnome DE. My Grub is black in colour since then. I am hoping to reinstall Grub to match with Unity I have now. I do not have any other DE s for now. Does reinstalling Grub give me stock 16.04 ? If yes, give me the commands, please.

Update :

Reinstalling Grub has no effect on Gnome-ish black elements while booting, sadly.

Update 1 :

I am not looking to change colour. I tried reinstalling Grub to remove Gnome-ish elements and get dotted boot screen by Ubuntu during start up and shutdown.

Comment: If you upgraded, you may have bits &  pieces of old install. You have all the installed apps which you want, but have many old log files which you do not need. Often easier for newer users to use Ubuntu live installer and add Boot-Repair ppa. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair But you can also use command line: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Comment: If you just care about how your GRUB looks, you can change that using [`grub-customizer`](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)

Comment: @oldfred I upgraded almost a year back, if that matters.

Comment: @zwork , how to use that ?

Comment: @user227495 add the ppa: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`, then install it: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install grub-customizer`

Comment: @user227495 its a graphical tool, so you can launch it by searching in unity for GRUB Customizer and then mess around with it. [This page](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43471/how-to-configure-the-linux-grub2-boot-menu-the-easy-way/) talks about using it